# Flutter Google Auth Error: The caller does not have the permission to execute the specific operation

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

i have try to login with GOOGLE it keeps showing this error: if i run it from my system.

> The caller does not have the permission to execute the specific
> operation

but if i send the apk to someone it will login successfully.

**firestore Rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null; 
    }
  }
}
```

**the code of the google auth.**
**Note:** this is working with same phone that is given that error if i generate the release apk.

```
final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

Future<bool> google() async {
    try {
      final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
      );
      users = (await auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      if (users == null) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      print('this is error .......$e');
      return null;
    }
  }
```

[image: Blockquote]

Comment: From the screenshot, this is a Firestore error. But your title says it's a Google auth error. Please post the part of the code that triggers this error.

Comment: okay. i will update the code now.

Comment: i have update the code.

Comment: Okay, when does the code throw the error and when does it work as expected?

Comment: @VictorEronmosele it works if i generate the apk and install it to this phone that is given error, but if they run the code and use that same phone it will throw that error

Comment: Okay, so when you generate the apk, is it a release build or a debug build?

Comment: is in app-release.apk

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the debug SHA-1 and add it to the Firebase Console.

You can generate the key by running these commands:

```
cd android
./gradlew signingReport
```

And this will return:

```
> Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: /Users/gbenga/.android/debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: <md5-key>
SHA1: <sha1-key>
SHA-256: <sha256-key>
Valid until: Tuesday, December 1, 2048
```

You can then copy the SHA-1, add it to the Firebase Console and redownload the `google-services.json` file again.

Add the file to `android/app` and run `flutter clean`.

Check out this [blog post](https://petercoding.com/firebase/2021/05/24/using-google-sign-in-with-firebase-in-flutter/) with more details.